# Sparsification and critical clauses in SAT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, lo.logic, sat, exp-time-algorithms

I have been studying the Exponential-Time Hypothesis, ETH, from this [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yr5VuySJw79DVOnbBY0AQ6IjVJQzvTyo/view?usp=drivesdk), there defined $s_k = \inf\{\delta \geq 0 | k\text{-}SAT \in RTIME[2^{\delta n}]\}$.

But in that paper's page number 10, I see this theorem, $s_k \leq (1 − \Omega(k^{−1}))s_{\infty}.$

My question is how to prove this theorem, is there any sources are available?

And is it also possible to prove
$s_k$ strictly increases $(s_{k+1} > s_k)$ for an infinite number of the values of $k?$ What hypothesis do we need for this? And Why?

Any help or hints are most welcomed.

Helpful reference maybe this [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iI6byUc6azTMOgRiCXIoE5sAK4J_rRop/view?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: Can you email the author to ask?

Comment: If there is no one in your department who can help, you will have to email one of those authors politely and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial answer existed in the paper, [On the Complexity of k-SAT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iI6byUc6azTMOgRiCXIoE5sAK4J_rRop/view?usp=drivesdk) by
Russell Impagliazzo and Ramamohan Paturi, 374 page, Theorem 3.