# Calculation on Sparsification and critical clauses in SAT

Tags: reference-request, time-complexity, sat, exp-time-algorithms

I followed from this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53820/sparsification-and-critical-clauses-in-sat).

I need to prove, the final result $s_k \leq (1 − \Omega(k^{−1}))s_{\infty}.$

But before prove the final result first I need to prove the $s_k \leq (1 − d/k))s_{\infty}$.
This prove existed in the paper, [On the Complexity of k-SAT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iI6byUc6azTMOgRiCXIoE5sAK4J_rRop/view?usp=drivesdk) by
Russell Impagliazzo and Ramamohan Paturi, 374 page, Theorem 3.

In that paper, one calculation I am not able to understand, which is,

$2^{h(\delta)n}+2^{\epsilon n}+2^{\epsilon n}2^{(s_k+ \epsilon)(1-(\delta/ek))n} \leq 2^{(s_\infty(1-d/k)+2\epsilon)n}$

,where $h(\delta) \leq s_\infty/2$ ,
$d \approx s_{\infty}/(2e\log(2/s_{\infty}))$ and, $\epsilon$ is  arbitrarily small.

My question is how to get $s_k \leq (1 − d/k))s_{\infty}$ from the above inequality? If I plug the  value of $h(\delta)$ and ignore the $\epsilon$ related terms, also unable to deduce $s_k \leq (1 − d/k))s_{\infty}$.

And my second question is that how to get final result $s_k \leq (1 − \Omega(k^{−1}))s_{\infty}$ from $s_k \leq (1 − d/k))s_{\infty}$?

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463578/complexity-analysis-on-sparsification-and-critical-clauses-in-sat . You were told many times before this is against the site rules.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not your personal tutor, and these basic calculations are not appropriate for this site, which is for *research-level* questions. You should post such questions at https://math.stackexchange.com or https://cs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part:

$2^{h(\delta)n}+2^{\epsilon n}+2^{\epsilon n}2^{(s_k+ \epsilon)(1-(\delta/ek))n} \leq 2^{(s_\infty(1-d/k)+2\epsilon)n}$

$\implies2^{(s_\infty/2)n} + 2^{(s_k+ \epsilon)(1-(\delta/ek))n +\epsilon n} \leq 2^{(s_\infty(1-d/k)+2\epsilon)n}$

$\implies  2^{(s_k+ \epsilon)(1-(\delta/ek))n +\epsilon n} \leq 2^{(s_\infty(1-d/k)+2\epsilon)n}-2^{(s_\infty/2)n}\approx 2^{(s_\infty(1-d/k)+2\epsilon)n}$

$\implies 2^{(s_k+ \epsilon)}\leq 2^{(s_\infty(1-d/k)}
(\because (1-(\delta/ek)) \approx 1 \space \text {and} \space \epsilon \space \text {is arbitrarily small})$

$\implies s_k \leq s_\infty(1-d/k)$

Second part:

Since in that paper mentioned, $d \approx s_{\infty}/(2e\log(2/s_{\infty}))$ and we are given from first part $s_k \leq s_\infty(1-d/k)$, how to get $s_k \leq (1 − \Omega(k^{−1}))s_{\infty}$? Need anybody's help.

Comment: I really have no idea what goes in your mind wrt the second part. Since $d$ is a *constant*, $s_k\le s_\infty(1-d/k)$ means $s_k\le s_\infty(1-\Omega(k^{-1}))$ directly from the definition of $\Omega$, there is nothing to prove here.